# What does this code block mean in javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
Template.body.helpers({
    tasks() {
      return Tasks.find({});
    },
});
```

I just know the basics of javaScript..but I saw this piece of code in meteor tutorial and did not understand what it meant,is task an object or a function?How does this actually give info to the HTML page?

Comment: Hi ,I am new to the javascript too, but after I have seen the code couple of times ,I would say ,any name with paranthesis () is a function name .Secondly task() has been called to return a value .So only function can return a value I believe.SO it's a function which has been called .Let me know how you going on .thanks

Comment: Please keep in mind, according to SO [guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if one of the answers works for you, you should mark them as an answer. If neither of them works, you should leave a comment and specify the reasons. Otherwise, there is no point in all of this questioning and answering.

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the `Template.body.helpers` is a [dictionary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Dict.jsm) which acts very similar to an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), so you can set multiple properties in it, like functions. The `tasks()` itself is a function which is responsible returning data from our database *(We know the Tasks are like this `const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');` so it is connected to the `tasks` table)*, in this particular case our query (`find({})`) does not include any condition so it will return all the data from the `tasks` table. The meteor engine will take the rest of it where you can refer to your helpers by `{{tasks}}`.

So you can create as many helpers as you want to do what you desired just like this:

```js
Template.body.helpers({
    tasks() {
      return Tasks.find({});
    },
    foo() {
      return Session.get("foo");
    }
});
```

Then you can refer both `foo` and `tasks` in your HTML like before with `{{foo}}` and `{{tasks}}`.

Answer (score 2):

It is the function, to which you are passing an object as an argument.
In this object there is method called "tasks".

---

```
tasks() {
      return Tasks.find({});
}
```

is the same as

```
tasks: function(){
    return Tasks.find({});
)
```

It is ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It's ES6+.

`Template.body.helpers` is receiving a JS Object/JSON which has a `function` called `tasks`. And it get all the information from `Tasks` object (defined anywhere in the same code), with empty query (which'd like all).

```
Template.body.helpers({
  tasks: function () {
    return Tasks.find({});
  },
});
```